# check whether a string contains white spaces and more than one @ signs

Tags: java, regex

I need to check whether a string contains white spaces commas and more than one @ signs.  I used the following method to do so, but it didn't work properly for me.

```
boolean flag = string.matches("\\s,@");
```

Can anyone of you tell me what has gone wrong in it?

Comment: `String.matches()` only works if the _entire_ string matches the supplied regexp.  That means you need to anchor both ends with `.*` to account for the characters either side of the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\s]|@.*@");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(your_string);
boolean  b = m.find();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following loop,

```
boolean isWhiteSpace = false;
boolean isDoubleOccur = false;
boolean flag = false;
for(int i =0; i<str.length; i++)
{
  if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
        isWhiteSpace = true;
  else if(str.charAt(i) == '@'){
        if(flag == true){
            flag = false;
            isDoubleOccur = true;
        } 
       flag = true;
  }             
}
```

Then you can use both isWhiteSpace and isDoubleOccur to check.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with indexOf(char), no need for regexp here.

Answer (score 1):

Without a regex manual at my side, \s,@ looks for one character of whitespace follwed by one comma followed by one @. i.e. the literal string " ,@" is the only thing that matches.

You don't specify if order or number of each char is important.

Comment: Any single whitespace character, not just " ", but yes. :)